# The greatest common divisor (GCD) of two integers is the largest integer that will evenly divide both integers in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, greatest-common-divisor

**Here is the Question:**

The greatest common divisor (GCD) of two integers is the largest integer that will evenly divide
both integers. The GCD algorithm involves integer division in a loop, described by the following
C++ code:

```
int GCD(int x, int y)
{
x = abs(x); // absolute value
y = abs(y);
do {
int n = x % y;
x = y;
y = n;
} while (y > 0);
return x;
}
```

Implement this function in assembly language and write a test program that calls the function several times, passing it different values. Display all results on the screen.

**Here the assembly language code that I am trying:**

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
array SDWORD -4,-20,36,24,11,9,448,224,15,-30
str1 BYTE "Greatest common divisor is: ",0

.code
main PROC

    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF array / 2
    mov  esi,OFFSET array

L1: mov  eax,[esi]
    mov  ebx,[esi+4]
    call findGCD
    mov  edx,OFFSET str1
    call WriteString
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    add  esi,TYPE array * 2
    loop L1

    exit
main ENDP
 
findGCD PROC

    push ebx
    push edx

    .IF SDWORD PTR eax < 0
      neg eax
    .ENDIF

    .IF SDWORD PTR ebx < 0
      neg ebx
    .ENDIF

L1: mov  edx,0
    div  ebx
    cmp  edx,0
    je   L2
    mov  eax,ebx
    mov  ebx,edx
    jmp  L1

L2: mov eax,ebx ; EAX = GCD

    pop edx
    pop ebx
    ret
findGCD ENDP

END main
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you run it?  This isn't a [mcve] - missing wrong vs. desired output.

Comment: first it says duplicate declaration of L1 and then its start giving error in third line which is array SDWORD -4,-20,36,24,11,9,448,224,15,-30

Comment: So don't declare local labels more than once.  Use @L1 or whatever MASM's local label syntax is, or give them meaningful unique names.  Also, [edit] your question to be a [mcve], quoting the exact error message.  Don't just leave stuff hidden in comments.

Comment: tried man but its giving error in other section of code.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have two labels with same name i.e., two `L1` labels. You can't assemble this unless you give the labels different names.

The second `L1` label is a loop that will keep looping until remainder is zero. You can rename it to something useful so that your code is easy to read / understand:

```
WhileRemNotZero:
    mov  edx,0
    div  ebx
    cmp  edx,0
    je   L2
    mov  eax,ebx
    mov  ebx,edx
    jmp  WhileRemNotZero
```

The rest of your code is fine. It will print the following for every 2 numbers (which imo is not a very good approach):

```
Greatest common divisor is: 2 //just a number, don't take it as actual result
```

Personally, I would just calculate GCD for the whole array and then print the result only once.

Comment: after changing L1 its getting error in the 3rd line

Comment: You will have to share the *error message* since I don't have your computer and can't read your mind.